# I can't flag a post on Area 51 even though I have 15 reputation

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, area-51

I can't flag a post even though I have over 15 reputation on Area 51. It still says I have flags remaining. I have not been banned from flagging. Why?

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you click the "Flag Question" button?

Comment: I am trying to raise a flag on Area 51.

Comment: @AnthonyLahmann next time you report a bug, please keep in mind **details are super crucial**. Without them, we have no way to help you, and as you see, without telling exactly what is wrong, you mislead people and get wrong replies. If you told from the beginning you mean Area 51, your question would have been received a lot better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flagging on Area 51 requires [**50** reputation](https://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts), not **15** as on all other sites in the network. Area 51's privilege levels are very different from [other sites in the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/295232) because it's an old codebase and reputation gains are different as well.

Since you gain [+50 reputation](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) by confirming your email address, it's rather easy to obtain this privilege and be able to flag the post.

Comment: I confirmed my email address but I only got 40 reputation.

Comment: I remember from looking at your profile yesterday that you had some other contributions on Area 51 (I don't see them anymore now), maybe they caused a loss of reputation? You could try to wait a day and see if your reputation gets recalculated.

Answer (score 6):

I just checked your Stack Overflow account. You have never had 15 reputation there, or if you once did, it was from something that doesn't show up in the audit (e.g. an upvote that was revoked before the lock-in period expired).

You have 13 rep now. Get one good suggested edit and you are good to raise flags!

Comment: Why does it have to be Stack Overflow? On Area 51 I have 41 reputation, enough to flag posts.

Comment: [It's 50 on Area51, @AnthonyLahmann](https://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts) - a little different from other sites

Comment: @Shog9 this really fits as answer, not just a comment which the OP can't even see unless coming back to read the answer by chance.